# How to treat diminished CTA buttons

Tags: colours

Let's say you have a page that has a prominent CTA in a big blue button (say SIGN UP!) and a diminished CTA beside it, as an underlined link ("No Thanks"). In the body copy of the page is sprinkled a few text links, underlined in blue.

My question is: is it cool to have this link a different colour than the usual text links throughout the page? Perhaps gray? Or should a link be a link, even if it's acting as a button?

...Does that make sense?

Comment: this might be useful http://www.designbyfire.com/deye_web/alertbox.htm

Comment: @kdanielz what is the primary activity here?

Answer (score 1):

When a word such as Cancel is right next to an obvious call to action button then I don't think the color matters too much.

[image]

I would caution against using grey colours as it could be interpreted as a disabled or an inactive link.

[image]

Comment: generally as a rule I'd agree. For something like SE for avid users this is a learned system and this set of functionality is deemed secondary therefore diminished, meaning it can get away with being less obvious. That's my take anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What is the semantics of the action controls in UI?  As best I can tell

- CALL TO ACTION!
- Information to support CTA
- avoid action

It is good to style semantically different items differently.  So yes, style all three differently.

To increase conversions rates, it may make sense to have a low visual priority for "avoid action". But do test, as this could frustrate your user base.